# gulp-file-include and navbar class="active"

Tags: gulp

I use gulp-file-include to combine many html file with the same header.

src/_header.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

src/index.html

```
@@include('_header.html')
index blah...
```

src/about.html

```
@@include('_header.html')
about blah...
```

Can I make the render result page like below?

With a class="active" on different nav item of each page.

dist/index.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
index blah...
```

dist/about.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
about blah...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a WORKAROUND , maybe there is a better solution.
But for now try this....

src/_header.html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="@@activeclassHome">Home</li>
    <li class="@@activeclassAbout">About</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

src/index.html

```
@@include('_header.html', {activeclassHome": "active", "activeclassAbout": ""})
```

src/about.html

```
@@include('_header.html', {activeclassHome": "", "activeclassAbout": "active"})
```

**rendered pages:**

dist/index.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

dist/About.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

UPDATE: Better use **[Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/)**
*a template engine to be used in client/server*

Comment: i'm not allowed to attach a screenshoot, so here is one on imgur:
https://i.imgur.com/EcZGBg8.png

Answer (score 2):

I used gulp-file-include if statement

src/_header.html

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="@@if (context.page === 'home') {active}">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="@@if (context.page === 'about') {active}">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

src/index.html

```
@@include('_header.html', {
"page": "home"
})
```

src/about.html

```
@@include('_header.html', {
"page": "about"
})
```

rendered pages:

dist/index.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

dist/about.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```